# c# array program that asks user to type in elements of an array and deletes all numbers that are equal to 0 fr

Tags: c#

Write a program that a asks user to type in elements of an array and deletes all numbers that are equal to 0 from the array. 
i keep getting stuck , how would you do it? please give an example.

Comment: What are you stuck with?

Comment: _"please give an example."_ **You mean please do it for me!!!**

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a do-my-homework-for-me website. You need to show what you have tried so that we can guide you to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be good clear, simple line - reads, creates array and than filter it. Perfect solution for beginner's homework:

```
var r = Enumerable.Repeat(0, int.MaxValue).Select(i => Console.ReadLine())
       .TakeWhile(s => s != null).Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray()
       .Where(i => i != 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: **Perfect solution for beginner's homework:**. Lol. You, sir, have won a copy of the internet.