# Read console input as enumerable - one statement?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there shorter/nicer way to read input in console as enumerable using standard features of C#/.Net 4.0? I don't think there is any practical usage of it, more as excercise.

This is what I quickly come up as an answer to homework question about "[read array/filter it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756608/c-sharp-array-program-that-asks-user-to-type-in-elements-of-an-array-and-deletes)". Basically I tried to write console equialent of [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx).

```
var completeConsoleInput = Enumerable.Repeat(0, int.MaxValue)
   .Select(i => Console.ReadLine()) 
   .TakeWhile(s => s != null);
```

I especially don't like `Enumerable.Repeat(0, int.MaxValue)` that I tried to use as "forever" iterator, but I don't remember seeing other option.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines()
{
  string line;
  while(null != (line = Console.ReadLine()))
    yield return line;
}

public static void Main()
{
  string input = string.Join(ReadLines(), Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: +1. Good approach if one actually need to do it practically. But I'm still intrested in one that does fit in one statement.

Comment: It will be difficult : in order to use LINQ you must have a collection. This is why you used Enumerable.Repeat(0, int.MaxValue).

Answer (score 9):

[You're not the first to try this](http://blog.einbu.no/2009/03/parsing-textfiles-with-linq/), and with the help of one simple Extension Method (which resembles the method from schglurps) you can inline it easily into the LINQ query:

```
public static class TextReaderExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> AsEnumerable(this TextReader reader)
    {
        string line;
        while ((line=reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

Since `Console` exposes the `In` and `Out` as `TextReader` and `TextWriter` you can simply get all the lines using `Console.In.AsEnumerable()` to include it in the LINQ query. The same extension method works with any `TextReader`.

Comment: Thanks. Yours and schglurps' answers are useful from practical point of view. Accepted schglurps' as his was earlier, also it looks like there is no shorter "one statement" answer as there in no built iterator on Reader.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I was looking for a more generic solution. Ideally i would like to extend the System.Linq.Enumerable class, but since that is not possible i had to put it in another class.

Implementation:

```
public static class MyEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Repeat<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            yield return func();
        }   
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var completeConsoleInput = MyEnumerable.Repeat(Console.ReadLine)
                                       .TakeWhile(s=> s != null);
```

Comment: You can just `while (true) { }`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
// One line to read them all
var lines = Console.In.ReadToEnd().Split(new[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(lines.Length + " lines:");
foreach (var line in lines) Console.WriteLine(line);
```

You don't get your IEnumerable back until all lines are read, similar to File.ReadAllLines; but it is a one-liner using standard C# features :)